# Modify a file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file in this format

```
[file1]
username = admin
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

[file2]
username = admin
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000
```

I want to modify the username and password for both sections in the file using a bash script.

I need the output to be:

```
[file1]
username = user1
password = user1
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

[file2]
username = user2
password = user2
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000
```

This is the `sed` command which I tried:

```
sed 's/username = admin/username = user1/' file [file1] username = user1 password = ***** ips = X.X.X.X port = 8000 [file2] username = user1 password = ***** ips = X.X.X.X port = 8000
```

I am trying to use a sed command to achieve this but it finds and replaces all usernames and passwords with same value. Can anyone help me sort this out?

```
sed 's/username = admin/username = user1/' x
[file1]
username = user1
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

[file2]
username = user1
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000
```

Appreciate your help in advance!

-W

Comment: What `sed` command have your tried?

Comment: I tried this command:
sed 's/username = admin/username = user1/' file
[file1]
username = user1
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

[file2]
username = user1
password = *****
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

Comment: Edit your question and add that `sed` command there; make your question self-contained.

Comment: sed might not be the best choice for this. awk or perl or ruby or python or something would be better.

Comment: @wasay, good that you showed us what you tried, please always add them in your posts as we all are here to learn, add this your post now in CODE TAGS and see my answer if that helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

***Solution 1st:*** Taking the number from `file` string in the line and then adding it to `user` and `password` string lines.

```
awk '/file/{val=$0;gsub(/[a-zA-Z]|+|\[|\]/,"",val)} /^user/||/^password/{$NF="user"val} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In this approach simply having a variable `count` which will be incremented by `1` each time it sees `file` string on it.

```
awk '/file/{count++} /^user/||/^password/{$NF="user"count} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above codes too.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder! Your solution gives me exactly what I needed now but my usernames and passwords won't always align with the file number. For example:

file3 can have a username as user4 and password as user5.

[file3]
username = user4
password = user5
ips = X.X.X.X
port = 8000

My apologies for not being accurate in my ask and also not putting the command I tried.

Comment: @wasay, then please do let me know what is the logic to get those values of user and password which needs to be printed? It is not clear, please explain about its logic.